# Create and use youtube embed object w/ javascript api on mobile web browsers

Tags: javascript, android, youtube-api, swfobject

I'm trying to build a simple webapp that leverages the embedded youtube javascript api (http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html).  It works well on my Chrome, Safari, etc... but it fails to work on the Android and iOS web browsers because of its SWF object dependency.  I'm hoping for mobile compatibility.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a is there a way to get around this?

(My requirements are as one would expect: I have a youtube video id that I'd like to use to create an embedded youtube video object w/ javascript api access.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not well versed with Android, but I know that iOS devices will recognize and convert a  standard `<object><embed></embed></object>` Youtube embed code to a compatible player, as long as the object wasn't created with Javascript, such as with swfobject.

However, I'm not sure if the javascript controls will work in the mobile player. I've not tested this.

Unfortunately, there is not currently a way to interact with the html5 (`<iframe>`) embedded player. I'm not sure what the status is, but controlling the `<iframe>` player with javascript introduces some interesting challenges.